# REACT: How do you set a child component's state to its parent's state?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props, setstate

I would like the child component's state to update as the parent component's state updates. Any changes to parent state variables should be reflected in the child's state. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Edit:

My components are arranged in the following manner. I would like to access the parent's state from Child 2. By setting the Child 1 state to the parent's state, I will be able to do this.

Parent->Child 1->Child 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### State And Props

> React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one,
> and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the
> desired state.
>
> the data flow in react is “unidirectional” or “top-down”,
> Any state is always owned by some specific component, and any data or
> UI derived from that state can only affect components “below” them in
> the tree.
>
> If you imagine a component tree as a waterfall of props, each
> component’s state is like an additional water source that joins it at
> an arbitrary point but also flows down.
>
> This is why the state is often called local or encapsulated. It is not
> accessible to any component other than the one that owns and sets it. @reactjs

Therefore, You Should pass the state to the child component, also known as `prop`.

Edit:

the hierarchy will be like this:
App(*state* - `date`) => Child1(*prop* `date`, passing the same *prop* to the next child) => Child2(getting `date` from his parent - **Child1**)

Example (*based on [Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)*):

**`<App>:`**

*The root of the app.*

```
<ClockList date={this.state.date} />
```

**`<ClockList>:`**

*notice we are using props*

```
<Clock date={this.props.date} />
```

**`<Clock>:`**

```
import React from "react";

const Clock = (props) => {
  // Object Destructuring can also be done in the function itself.
  const { date } = props;
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <p>{date}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the part of the parent state that you need as a prop to the child.
Then each time the parent state will change, the child will rerender with the correct value.

If you need to change the state from within the child, it depends on the behaviour you want.

You can make the child change the parent state by passing a callback function as a prop (you can pass the function used to change the state in the parent as a prop to the child)

Or you can make the child local state beeing reset to the parent state when it changes by listening to changes on the prop with a useEffect or ComponentDidUpdate.

```
useEffect(() => { setState(props.partOfparentState)},[props.partOfparentState])
```

or

```
ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(previousProps.partOfParentState != props.partOfParentState) {
        partOfParentStatethis.setState({state:props.parpartOfParentStatetOfParentState})
    }
}
```

You could also want other behaviour which could be achieved with a more complex useEffect.

Comment: I'm using class components. Instead of setting the parent's state to the child's prop, I would like to set the child's state to the parent's state. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, If the child state shall be the same as the parent, you just need to pass the state as a prop and use the prop instead of the state.
Also I updated the answer for class.